# Net Core: Вызов метода атрибута

Tags: c#, атрибуты

**Код:**

```
//Attribute:
public class CommandAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CommandAttribute(Type customType);
    public Type customType { get; }
}



//Attributes applied to class Command1 to check access to Logic1() method:
[CommandAttribute(typeof(AddCustomAuthorization))]
public class Command  : BaseCommand
{
    public Command1() {}

    public void Logic1()
    {
        ////
    }
}

///Логика авторизации - как вызвать этот метод?
public class AddCustomAuthorization
{
    //How call it ???
    public override Task<bool> Authorize(Command command, ICurrentContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать метод **Authorize** атрибута **AddCustomAuthorization**?**

Мне кажется, что проверка доступа должна быть в констуркторе  Command1(), но как вызвать ее, я все еще не знаю.

Comment: Рефлексией наверное только.

Comment: Вызвать где? | Атрибуты это не код, это метаданные. Сами по себе они не выполняются. Нужно рефлексией получить атрибут и вручную сделать с ним какие-либо действия.

Comment: Судя по всему, тебе нужны не атрибуты, а методы расширения https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: @AntonNikolaev  к сожалению есть только атрибут

Comment: `var attribute = command.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<CommandAttribute>(); if (attribute is null) { /* нет атрибута */ }`. дальше пользуемся `attribute`. или я чего-то не понимаю?